# How to use stripecheckout in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I am new in vue js . I am trying to add payment system with stripe. I made a component of Stripecheckout and add it in my checkout component. @vue-stripe/vue-stripe is installed and enabled the client only integration. Here is my source code:

StripeCheckout.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <stripe-checkout
      ref="checkoutRef"
      mode="payment"
      :pk="publishableKey"
      :line-items="lineItems"
      :success-url="successURL"
      :cancel-url="cancelURL"
      @loading="v => loading = v"
    />
    <button @click="submit">Pay now!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { StripeCheckout } from '@vue-stripe/vue-stripe';
export default {
  components: {
    StripeCheckout,
  },
  data () {
    this.publishableKey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
    return {
      loading: false,
      lineItems: [
        {
          price: localStorage.getItem('total'),
        },
      ],
      successURL: 'www.facebook.com',
      cancelURL: 'www.youtube.com',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      // You will be redirected to Stripe's secure checkout page
      //this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In Checkout.vue:

```
<template>
                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <span>Cash payment</span>
                        <img src="assets/images/payment.png" style='width:300px;margin-top:10px;' alt="">
                         
                           <StripeCheckout></StripeCheckout>
                    </div>
```

```
<script>
import StripeCheckout from './StripeCheckout.vue';
export default {
    
    name:'Checkout',

    components:{
        StripeCheckout
    }, 
  ....}
</script>
```

But the button option is displaying in checkout component but not working.
By clicking the pay button this is consoling.

Vue Stripe will not work on an insecure host. Make sure that your site is using TCP/SSL

Comment: "Vue Stripe will not work on an insecure host" seems pretty clear. You need HTTPS.

Comment: And  how do I do that?

Comment: That'll depend a lot on how you're running your webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Add `stripe` reference in your `public/index.html`

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

***Step 2:*** Create and `Checkout` component

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="row payment-form">
      <h5 class="#e0e0e0 grey lighten-4">
        Payment Method
        <span class="right">$25</span>
      </h5>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 s12 card-element">
          <label>Card Number</label>
          <div id="card-number-element" class="input-value form-control form-control-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 s6 card-element">
          <label>Expiry Date</label>
          <div id="card-expiry-element"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 s6 card-element">
          <label>CVC</label>
          <div id="card-cvc-element"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="error red text-center white-text">{{stripeValidationError}}</div>
      <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col s12 place-order-button-block text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2"  type="button" @click.prevent="placeOrder">Place Order</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'checkout',
  data () {
    return {
      stripe:null,
      cardNumberElement:null,
      cardExpiryElement:null,
      cardCVCElement:null,
      stripeValidationError: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.drinkDetails)
    this.stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') // add your stripe key
    this.createAndMountFormElements()
  },
  methods: {
    createAndMountFormElements() {
      var elements = this.stripe.elements()
      this.cardNumberElement = elements.create('cardNumber')
      this.cardNumberElement.mount('#card-number-element')
      this.cardExpiryElement=elements.create('cardExpiry')
      this.cardExpiryElement.mount('#card-expiry-element')
      this.cardCvcElement=elements.create('cardCvc')
      this.cardCvcElement.mount('#card-cvc-element')
      this.cardNumberElement.on('change', this.setValidationError)
      this.cardExpiryElement.on('change', this.setValidationError)
      this.cardCvcElement.on('change', this.setValidationError)
    },
    setValidationError(event) {
      console.log('setValidationError', event)
      this.stripeValidationError = event.error ? event.error.message : ''
    },
    placeOrder () {
      this.stripe.createToken(this.cardNumberElement).then(result => {
        console.log('result', result)
        if (result.error) {
          this.stripeValidationError = result.error.message
        } else if (result.token) {
          console.log('token', result.token)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .payment-form {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
  }
  .payment-form h5 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .card-element {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  #card-number-element,
  #card-expiry-element,
  #card-cvc-element {
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
  }
  .place-order-button-block {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  button {
    background-color: $app-bgm;
  }
</style>
```

***Step 3:*** Clicking the `Place Order` button you will get the `stripe` `token`. Using the stripe token you have to pass the token to `backend` `rest api` call you have to debit the money.

Install backend stripe installation for npm package

```
npm install stripe --save
```

You can debit the money from `debit/credit card` using below method,

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
let user = await stripe.customers.create({ email: 'xxxx@gmail.com', payment_method: token });
await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 25 * 100, // $25
  currency: 'usd',
  customer: user
})
```

[image]